# why is this error "Details: "We found extra characters at the end of JSON input." when I tried to load JSON files in power bi

Tags: json, twitter, powerbi

I am new to Power BI. When I tried uploading JSON files in a folder I am getting this error:

> ```
> DataFormat.Error: We found extra characters at the end of JSON input.
> Details:
>     Value={
>     Position=3003
> ```

Is there any possible solution to this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure the JSON is valid? Check it with https://jsonformatter.org/ or some other validator.

Comment: Can you please share your json string/file?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. I found some other way, but thank you very much